# How to check if the variable is an object or an array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am trying to check if the passed variable is an object or an array in php.

I have something like

```
if(is_object($product>item)) {
     if(isset($product->item->ArrayOfImage->path)) {
          $img = $product->item->ArrayOfImage->path
     }else{
          unset($img);
     }
}else{
    if(isset($product->item[$i]->ArrayOfImage->path)){  //$i is the index from a for loop
        $img = $product->item[$i]->ArrayOfImage->path
    }else{
        unset($img);
    }
}
```

The above codes will check whether `$product->item` is an object or not, if not, it treats it as array. It will also check if the value is set. I do feel like I could refactor it but not sure where to begin. Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: Why do you feel like you should refactor this? What's wrong? is it not working? We need to know these things

Comment: Guess you could change that `else` to `else if` including the [is_array()](http://is2.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) function. If neither fits, nothing is done. Otherwise if it's working I don't know what you're seeking.

Comment: You could use ternary notation for the `if/else` if all those words are getting you down...

Comment: Is it just me or did anyone else notice that two lines don't end in a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a php built-in function [`gettype`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) to detect the type of the variables:

```
string gettype ( mixed $var );
```

or you can use the [`is_object`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php) or [`is_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) functions to check the variable type:

```
bool is_array ( mixed $var )
bool is_object ( mixed $var )
```